# Overflow error in function

Tags: c, function, overflow

I'm new to C programming and I've been writing a virtual computer program that takes input from STDIN , the inputs basically represents commands that task the Virtual computer to perform a multiple of a certain number check - just simple stuff. Essentially when I first wrote this program I was reading my input from a file using file pointers that direct to file streams , but then when I switched my stream to STDIN it started getting weird.

The interesting thing about this STDIN is that it's a file stream redirection, so I am still providing a file in command line argument , but since I use a coding platform that has a command that allows file redirection without having to implement an actual file pointer it's getting me confused.

I started getting overflow errors that did not occur when I used to have file pointers to the programs that are being provided in the command line argument, I have no idea why as I have just switched my file pointer stream to stdin`, . I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out to me what the problem could likely be, here is the code that I'm getting the overflow errors from:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Calling in the prototypes NOTE: I don't call execute/compile because they preceed the main method */

int printMemory(int* accumulator, int* instructionCounter, int* instructionRegister,int*operationCode,int* operand, int memory []);
int checkSegmentationFault(int *operand);
int checkWordFlow(int instructionCounter, int memory []);

/* 
Function Name: compile
Parameters: A pointer to the file that we are processing, the memory array, a pointer to  instructionCounter, instructionRegister, operationCode, and operand, so that we can carry operations on them
Return value(s): returns 1 if it compiles succesfully otherwise it would return a zero or terminate.
Partners: None
Description: This function reads in the file through it's pointer line by line and then converts it's data into 4 digit values, then they get stored into memory array. The function the proceeds to check for some compiling errors then it returns the result.
*/

int compile (FILE* fPointer , int memory [], int* instructionCounter , int* instructionRegister ,int*operationCode ,int* operand){
    char s[80]; /* The buffer */
    *instructionRegister=0;
    *operationCode=0;
    while(((*instructionRegister)=fscanf(fPointer,"%d %s %d", operationCode,s,operand)) != EOF){ /*Reads data line by line then stores the integer returned by fscanf to instructionRegister pointer so that I can check for formating */
        if((*instructionRegister) ==3 ){ /*Checks for improper format by comparing the current instructionRegister count to 3, returns improper format otherwise */
            if(*operand >9999|| *operand <0){  /* Checks for word overflow in compiler, makes sure that digits do not exceed 9999 */
                printf("attempts to place a word in memory that is larger than 4 digits, or attempted to pass in a negative value\n ");
                exit(0);
            }
            /*Compares the string section of the code and checks if it matches the following words and then it converts it to it's 4 digit value by adding into it the operand */
            if(strcmp(s,"READ") == 0) {
                memory[*operationCode] = 10 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"WRIT") == 0) {
                memory [*operationCode] = 11 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"LOAD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 20 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"PRNT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 12 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"STOR") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 21 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SET") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"ADD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 30 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SUB") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 31 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"DIV") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 32 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MULT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 33 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MOD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 34 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRAN") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 40 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRNG") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 41 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRZR") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 42 * 100 + *operand;;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"HALT")==0){
                memory [*operationCode] =9999;
            }

            else {   /* Prints back to the user that the compiler did not recognize one of them commands as it was going through it */
                printf ("This is an unknown command, commands are case sensitive, program will now exit \n");
                exit(0);

            }
        }
        else{    /* Returns improper format if instructionRegister does not match 3*/
            printf("Improper Format, program will now exit \n");
            exit(0);
        }


    }
    /* Checks if the instruction data contains a HALT, if not it would terminate */
    while(*instructionCounter<100){
        if (memory[*instructionCounter] == 9999){
            return 1;
        }
        else
            (*instructionCounter)++;
    }
    printf("Halt was not found, program will now exit");    
    exit (0);

}
/*
Function Name       : execute
Parameters      : accumulator for storing in the arithematic operations , instructionCounter for counting the instructions, instructionRegisterfor storing the current instruction, 
operationCode stores the first 2 digits so that it would recognize what command is currently being executed, operand stores the next 2 digits , and the memory to be able to loop through the computer 100 memory
Return value(s)     : returns 1 if it executes fine, otherwise it would terminate if it finds an error. It also prints out HALT once found which shows the current state of the memory.
Partners            : None
Description     : This function processes the compiled instructions and start carrying out operations on them depending on their operation code, it also checks for error then it prints out the current memory state once it reaches HALT,
*/

int execute(int* accumulator ,  int* instructionCounter , int* instructionRegister ,int*operationCode ,int* operand, int memory [])
{
    /* Resets the values to zero because they were used in the compiler */
    *operand=0;
    *operationCode=0;
    *instructionRegister=0;
    *instructionCounter=0;
    *accumulator=0;

    /* this loop starts looking at the 4 digit memory cells and executes them 1 by 1  */
    while(*instructionCounter<100){

        checkWordFlow(*instructionCounter, memory);

        *instructionRegister=memory[*operand];  /*stores current instruction */

        *operand=memory[*instructionCounter]%100;   /* Stores the 2 right  digits  */

        checkSegmentationFault(operand);         /* checks that operand does not contain a negative value so that the problem does not throw a seg fault */

        *operationCode=memory[*instructionCounter]/100; /* Stores the 2 left diigts */

        if(*operationCode==10){ /*READ: inquires the user to provide input and stores it in specified address in the instructions*/

            scanf("%d",&memory[*operand]);

        }
        else if(*operationCode==11 ){ /*WRIT*: prints out the data in a memory element when executed*/
            printf("%d\n",memory[*operand]);
        }

        else if(*operationCode==12 ){ /*PRNT */

            while(1){   /*Loops and prints the followiing values that prnt passes in as operand */  

                /*Checks if the ASCI values are within the correct range */                
                if((memory[*operand]/100 > 65 &&memory[*operand]/100 <90)  || memory[*operand]/100 == 10 )
                    printf("%c",memory[*operand]/100);
                else if (memory[*operand]/100 == 0){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Unknown Character\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
                if((memory[*operand]%100>65 &&memory[*operand]%100 <90)  || memory[*operand]%100 == 10)
                    printf("%c", memory[*operand]%100);
                else if (memory[*operand]%100 == 0){
                    break;
                }

                else{
                    printf("Unknown Character\n");
                    exit(0);
                }

                (*operand)++;  
            }
            *operand =0;  /*Resets the value of operand since it was incremented, so that it wont mess up the HALT print*/
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(*operationCode==20 ){  /*LOAD : loads into the accumulator */
            *accumulator = memory[*operand];

        }
        else if(*operationCode== 21){  /*STORE: stores the accumlator value into the specific memory cell*/
            memory[*operand] = *accumulator;
        }

        else if(*operationCode==30 ){ /*ADD: adds into the accumulator the specificed memory address data*/
            *accumulator+=memory[*operand];
        }

        else if(*operationCode==31 ){ /*SUB: substracts from the accumulator the specified memoery addres data*/
            *accumulator= *accumulator - memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode== 32){ /*DIV: divides from the accumulator the specificed memory address data */

            if(memory[*operand] >0){ /* Handles division by zero error */
                *accumulator= *accumulator/memory[*operand];
            }
            else {
                printf("Division by zero was attempted\n program will now exit \n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if(*operationCode== 33){    /*MULT: multiplies to the accumulator the specified address data*/
            *accumulator= *accumulator*memory[*operand];
        }   
        else if(*operationCode== 34){  /*MOD: calculates the remainder to the accumulator the specified address data*/
            *accumulator= *accumulator%memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode ==40){  /*BRAN: jump memory execution to address given */
            *instructionCounter= *operand;
            (*instructionCounter)--;  /* deduct counter by 1 so that the loop does not skip over instructions */
        }
        else if(*operationCode ==41){ /*BRNG: jumps memory execution to addres given only if accumulator is negative*/

            if (*accumulator <0){        
                *instructionCounter=*operand;
                (*instructionCounter)--;  /* deduct counter by 1 so that the loop does not skip over instructions */

            }
        }
        else if(*operationCode ==42){  /*BRZR jumps memory execution to memory location only if accumulator is zero*/

            if(*accumulator ==0){        
                *instructionCounter=*operand;
                (*instructionCounter)--; /* deduct counter by 1 so that the loop does not skip over instructions */            
            }
        }
        else if(*operationCode == 99){  /*HALT: terminates the program but prints out the memory state before it does that*/
            printMemory(accumulator,instructionCounter,instructionRegister,operationCode,operand,memory); /*prints the memory out */
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(*operationCode == 0){ /* Checks for empty elements and moves passt them */
            (*instructionCounter)++;
            continue;
        }

        else{  /* Handles unrecognized operation codes */    
            printf("Unknown Command, program will now exit\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        (*instructionCounter)++;  /* Increment loop by 1 and start the next round of looping */

    }
    return 1;
}
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE * fPointer=NULL;
    char fileName[150];
    int accumulator=0;
    signed int instructionCounter=0;
    signed int instructionRegister=0;
    int operationCode=0;
    int operand=0;
    signed int memory [100];
    /*Checks if the user passed in an argument at the command  line*/
    if(argc < 1){
        puts("You didn't specify the arguments or parameters\n");
        exit(0);

    }
    /*fill the buffer */
    if(argc>1)
        strcpy(fileName,argv[1]);


    fPointer=stdin;
    /* If file failed to open then this would throw an error */
    if(fPointer == NULL){
        puts("File failed to open\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* This loop fills the memory array with zeros*/
    for(instructionCounter =0;instructionCounter<100;instructionCounter++){
        memory [instructionCounter] = 0; 
    }
    instructionCounter=0;


    /* Run the commands */

    compile(fPointer, memory,&instructionCounter,&instructionRegister,&operationCode,&operand);
    execute(&accumulator,&instructionCounter,&instructionRegister,&operationCode,&operand,memory);
    return 1;
}

/*
   Function Name       : printMemory
Parameters      : accumulator, instructionCounter, instructionRegister, operationCode, operand, memory array, to insure that we print out the correct state of the memory we have to pass them in 
Return value(s)     : returns 1, but prints out memory state before it does that
Partners            : None
Description     : Prints out the current state of the memory in a nicely formatted manner
*/

int printMemory(int* accumulator , int* instructionCounter , int* instructionRegister ,int*operationCode ,int* operand, int memory []){
    printf("REGISTERS:\naccumulator              %+05d\ninstructionCounter          %02d\ninstructionRegister      %+05d\noperationCode               %02d\noperand                     %02d\n",
            *accumulator, *instructionCounter, *instructionRegister, *operationCode, *operand); 
    *instructionCounter =0;

    printf("MEMORY:\n       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9\n");
    for((*instructionCounter)=0;(*instructionCounter)<100;(*instructionCounter)+=10) /* loops through the memory array and outputs 10 elements in every row */
    {
        printf("%2d",*instructionCounter);
        printf(" %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d %+05d\n", memory[*instructionCounter], memory[*instructionCounter+1] , memory [*instructionCounter+2] , memory [*instructionCounter+3], memory[*instructionCounter+4],
                memory[*instructionCounter+5],memory[*instructionCounter+6],memory[*instructionCounter+7],memory[*instructionCounter+8],memory[*instructionCounter+9] );

    }
    return 1;
}
/*
   Function Name       : checksegmentationFault
Parameters      : operand.
Return value(s)     : returns 0, terminates the program if it tried to access an unknown operand , likely a negative value.
Partners            : None
Description     : terminates the program if it tried to access an unknown operand , likely a negative value.,
*/

int checkSegmentationFault(int *operand)
{
    if(*operand < 0 || *operand >100){
        printf("SEGMENTATION FAULT: Attempted to access an unknown address \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
   Function Name       : checkWordFlow
Parameters      : instructionCounter for looping, and memory array
Return value(s)     : 1 , terminates if it reaches a word overflow
Partners            : None
Description     : this function checks for the word overflow possible error at execution by checking that digit values do no surpass 9999,
*/

int checkWordFlow( int instructionCounter, int memory []) /*fix this shit */
{
    instructionCounter=0;
    while(instructionCounter<100){
        if(memory[instructionCounter]>9999)
        { printf("Word Overflow at memory element %d\n program will exit\n", instructionCounter);
            exit(0);
        }
        instructionCounter++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The stream of input looks something like this: (Like I mentioned above this stream is being redirected with a VIM command, it cheats the program into reading from files without having to actually implement file pointers)

```
01 READ 60
02 LOAD 60
03 SUB 61
04 STOR 60
05 BRNG 15
06 READ 70
07 LOAD 70
08 ADD 80
09 STOR 80
10 LOAD 60
11 SUB 61
12 STOR 60
13 BRNG 15
14 BRAN 6
15 WRIT 80
16 HALT 99
61 SET 1
80 SET 0
```

I've been scratching my head for hours and I cannot figure out why it's doing that, as I said I'm new to C programming and I still don't know how to debug and do the C stuff, I came from a Java background.

Edit 1: The user does not write the program to the virtual computer, the programs are already written and the user just redirects with a STDIN  via a command in VIM like this     `(./computer < prog1)` or     `(./computer < prog2)`. The program should compile successfully, and then when the computer figures out what kind of a program it is , it will prompt the user for input depending on it's task. So it could ask the user to input values , then it would calculate their average if that was the program that was redirected to it.

Comment: Consider separating concerns.  You had code that worked for you using `FILE *` streams.  You can access the standard input via just such a stream, declared in stdio.h as `stdin`.  I suggest taking your old, working code, and replacing the `fopen()` call with `stdin` (i.e. `myFilePointer = stdin;`.  This will help you rule out the unlikely proposition that the problem has anything to do with the details of the manner of input.

Comment: You claim to use `gets()`, but I see no `gets()` calls in the code you posted.  That's good, because if there were any then I would urge you to remove them, because `gets()` is inherently flawed and should never be used.  The problem is so serious that `gets()` has actually been removed from C2011 -- it is extremely rare for features to be altogether removed.

Comment: Thank you I will try to do that now!

Comment: You say you get "overflow errors" but I'm not sure what that means.  If you're saying that some other part of your code behaves differently than you expect, then you should consider that the problem may be *there*.  We generally expect troubleshooting questions to be accompanied by a [mcve].  That means not just any code, but *minimal*, *complete* code with which we can reproduce the problem, plus input data and expected results.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I switched my fopen call in the original to stdin but it's still throwing overflows at me now in the original

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will edit my code now to provide the full program

Comment: I have edited my code now , as you can see in the main function I have my file pointers from the original code and I just simply switched the poiner to stdin for the stream but it still would not work.

Comment: We can maybe work with this, but you have clearly not fully understood the **minimal** part of "minimal, complete, and verifiable".  We don't ordinarily want your whole code; we want something with as much unnecessary cruft cut out as possible.  Preparing such a thing is a useful exercise in its own right, as it often helps you discover the error yourself.

Comment: I'm still not sure what an "overflow error" is, but if you're talking about the test performed by function `checkWordFlow()` then your program runs the sample input for me without triggering the diagnostic therein.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I figured out the problem :)! So basically if I am inputting the values with STDIN manually instead of redirecting them with that VIM command, the program works! The thing is when I am doing then manually I do CTRL+D and that signals the end of the program , and then the user is prompted to input the values for the program! SO Basically in the stream it does not have a ctrl+D to tell it to stop , so how can I make it stop

Comment: Your program works for me *with* I/O redirection, both via the shell and indirectly from `vim` (which anyway just launches a shell to run the program).  And it should.  When you use I/O redirection, end-of-file is indicated by the physical end of the file; you do not need a special character in the stream for that purpose.

Comment: For me it only works when I am doing manual STDIN for the program , indicating it's end with CTRL D, but the shell command is not working :(. That's what's driving me nuts! I have EOF comparision so why does it overflow when it's doing it with the shell command? very strange.

Comment: If you get different results when the program's stdin is connected to a terminal than when it is connected to a file, despite feeding it the same data, then I'm inclined to think that you're not running the same program in those two cases.  Alternatively, maybe you're not actually feeding it the same input.

Comment: Maybe the shell command that VIM is using requires a certain setup? I just double checked and the program is exactly the same! , is it okay if I show you what's going on with a screen-share program?

Comment: I think the VIM shell command is preventing it from receiving the same input, does the file it's reading require a \n at very end or something ?

Comment: No, I will not participate in any kind of screen sharing.  Any information needed to answer the question should be presented *in* the question.

Comment: I doubt that `vim` is contributing to the problem, but I do suggest simplifying the problem space by taking `vim` out of it.  Run the program directly from the (same) shell, both with and without I/O redirection.  If the latter still fails, then present the input that causes it to fail, and the program output indicative of the failure.

Comment: Yes, I took the exact code you presented and compiled it.  I took the example input you presented, put it in a file, and ran the program, redirecting its input from the file.  The program printed a `0`, a summary of registers, and a memory map.  It did not emit any diagnostic messages.

Comment: Alright, it should not behave like that, thanks for clarifying .The program should works in two steps: First - it will take input of the program that the user wants , reads line by line , as commands, just like a virtual computer in the compiler. Second - If compilation process was a success it will go to execution now and it will execute the program that the user provided, Now when the program executes it will prompt the user to enter two values , and it should take inputs from user, the program above has the following task: sums the total of integers that the user inputs

Comment: This  programreads in two numbers and if the second number is a multiple of the first outputs the string “MULT” otherwise outputs the string “NOT”, here are the commands for it 01 READ 51
02 READ 52
03 LOAD 52
04 MOD 51
05 BRZR 08
06 PRNT 90
07 HALT 99
08 PRNT 80
09 HALT 99
80 SET 7785
81 SET 7684
82 SET 1000
90 SET 7879
91 SET 8410
92 SET 0000
, That one is giving me an overflow in the shell

Comment: Wait, what?  The program tries to read the VM program AND additional inputs from the same stream?  Now I understand what you said earlier about ctrl+D (and this is one reason why we want a *minimal* example).  Yes, you do need a way to mark the boundary between VM instructions and VM data if you are reading them from the same stream.  That Ctrl+D works for you when you input the data by hand is a shell quirk.  I'd suggest adding a VM pseudo-instruction that serves to mark the end of the program source.  "END" or "STOP" might be a reasonable name.

Comment: Yes that is  exactly the technical term for it :D ! It was reading both from the same stream and I could not figure out if EOF was supposed to stop that but it was not, so if I add a STOP at the very last line and like make an if block that has a break in it , it would work right? Also do you think there is another way to do this without having to write a termination command at the very end?

Comment: I tried adding the following if block within the while loop       `if(strcmp(s,"STOP")==0){
                break;}`  I also added a `00 STOP 00`, at the very last line of the program that I'm giving into the shell but it did not work , it still gave overflow for the other programs and did not prompt the user to enter for the one in the example above

Comment: There is a variety of ways you could mark the boundary between sections of the input.  It does not have to be a (pseudo)instruction, but that would have the advantage of fitting very cleanly into your existing code.  It is unreasonable, however, to rely on a stream-level end-of-input signal between sections, because once you see EOF on a stream, it is unsafe to assume that any further data can be read from it (unless you first successfully reposition with `fseek()` or such).

Comment: I thought break would terminate a while loop, however it seems like it's constantly looping even after providing a break for the  loop, maybe I should redirect the stdin to the user terminal with something like this : stdin = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");

Comment: I added the same line for handling a STOP command, and recompiled.  I added the same `00 STOP 00` to the vm program file, and I added an additional integer after it to be read by the `READ` vm instruction.  The vm runs successfully and accepts both parts of the input.  If I remove the STOP instruction from the vm program file, it instead fails with an "Improper Format" message.  This all seems right, and exactly what I would expect.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you sooooo much John! I learn something new everyday in this world of C haha! Sorry for sending so many comments I was just really frustrated! Thank you again alot , have a great day

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking the input from the user, then the code will be different.

There are a few options,

1. Keep the same code, but put a condition on the user to press `Ctrl-Z` after entering all the data. This will only work if you are the only person entering the data, and is generally not workable.
2. After every loop, you can ask the user if he wants to enter more data. Then you can get the input as a `y/n` and loop back if the user enters `y`.

An example is below.

```
do
{
  scanf("%d %79s %d",operationCode,s,operand));
  // Other code here

   printf("\n Do you want to enter another value (y/n) ");
   scanf(" %c",&check);
} while(check != 'n");
```

3. Loop for a fixed no of times, but your original code does not work that way and this will not be a good option for you.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I use VIM for programming and it has a tool within it that auto redirects files as input when being provided in the command line argument so to execute the program I use something like this ./computer < prog1 , where prog1 is actually a file being read in via STDIN instead of having to implement file pointers. The user inputs values after the prog compiles succesfully depending on the program. Afterall it's a virtual computer :) .

Comment: @MohammedAl-Huneidi, note that `vim` is just giving you standard I/O redirection using the same syntax as the shell's.