# C Overflow when getting data from STDIN

Tags: c, overflow

I'm new to C programming and I've been writing a virtual computer program that takes input from STDIN , the inputs basically represents commands that task the Virtual computer to perform a multiple of a certain number check - just simple stuff. Essentially when I first wrote this program I was reading my input from a file using file pointers, but then when I switched my stream to STDIN it started getting weird.

The interesting thing about this STDIN is that it's a file stream redirection, so I am still providing a file in command line argument , but since I use a coding platform that has a command that allows file redirection without having to implement an actual file pointer it's getting me confused.

I started getting overflow errors that did not occur when I used to have file pointers to the programs that are being provided in the command line argument, I have no idea why as I have just switched my `fscanf` to a `gets`, and obviously deleted the file pointer stuff. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out to me what the problem could likely be, here is the function that I'm getting the overflow errors from:

```
int compile ( int memory [], int* instructionCounter , int* instructionRegister ,int*operationCode ,int* operand){
    char s[800]; /* The buffer */
    char temp[800];
    *instructionRegister=0;
    *operationCode=0;
    while(gets(temp)){ /*Reads data line by line then stores the integer      returned by fscanf to instructionRegister pointer so that I can check for formating */

    *instructionRegister=sscanf(temp,"%2d %s %d",operationCode,s,operand); 
       printf("%d %s %d\n",*operationCode,s,*operand);
        if((*instructionRegister) ==3 ){ /*Checks for improper format by


             comparing the current instructionRegister count to 3, returns improper format otherwise */
            if(*operand >9999|| *operand <0){  /* Checks for word overflow in compiler, makes sure that digits do not exceed 9999 */
                printf("attempts to place a word in memory that is larger than 4 digits, or attempted to pass in a negative value\n ");
                exit(0);
            }
            /*Compares the string section of the code and checks if it matches the following words and then it converts it to it's 4 digit value by adding into it the operand */
            if(strcmp(s,"READ") == 0) {
                memory[*operationCode] = 10 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"WRIT") == 0) {
                memory [*operationCode] = 11 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"LOAD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 20 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"PRNT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 12 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"STOR") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 21 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SET") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"ADD") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 30 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"SUB") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 31 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"DIV") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 32 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MULT") ==0){
                memory [*operationCode] = 33 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"MOD") ==0){
               memory [*operationCode] = 34 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRAN") ==0){
            memory [*operationCode] = 40 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRNG") ==0){
            memory [*operationCode] = 41 * 100 + *operand;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"BRZR") ==0){
            memory [*operationCode] = 42 * 100 + *operand;;
            }
            else if(strcmp(s,"HALT")==0){
            memory [*operationCode] =9999;
            }

        else {   /* Prints back to the user that the compiler did not recognize one of them commands as it was going through it */
            printf ("This is an unknown command, commands are case sensitive, program will now exit \n");
            exit(0);

        }
    }
    else{    /* Returns improper format if instructionRegister does not match 3*/
        printf("%d",*instructionRegister);
        printf("Improper Format, program will now exit \n");
        exit(0);
    }


}
/* Checks if the instruction data contains a HALT, if not it would terminate */
while(*instructionCounter<100){
    if (memory[*instructionCounter] == 9999){
        return 1;
    }
    else
        (*instructionCounter)++;
}
printf("Halt was not found, program will now exit");
exit (0); }
```

The stream of input looks something like this: (Like I mentioned above this stream is being redirected with a VIM command, it cheats the program into reading from files without having to actually implement file pointers)

```
01 READ 20
02 LOAD 20
03 BRNG 12
04 STOR 30
05 LOAD 60
06 ADD 30
07 STOR 60
08 LOAD 50
09 ADD 70
10 STOR 70
11 BRAN 01
12 LOAD 60
13 DIV 70
14 STOR 80
15 WRIT 80
16 HALT 99
50 SET 1
60 SET 0
70 SET 0
```

I have added a printf that prints out the contents being scanned to sscanf t the compiling process and here is what I get in the output , the first argument is operationCode an integer pointer ,2nd argument one is a string buffer s , third argument is operand which is an integer pointer) :

```
1 READ 20
2 LOAD 20
3 BRNG 12
4 STOR 30
5 LOAD 60
6 ADD 30
7 STOR 60
8 LOAD 50
9 ADD 70
10 STOR 70
11 BRAN 1
12 LOAD 60
13 DIV 70
14 STOR 80
15 WRIT 80
16 HALT 99
50 SET 1
60 SET 0
70 SET 0
Word Overflow at memory element 70
 program will exit
```

I've been scratching my head for hours and I cannot figure out why it's doing that, as I said I'm new to C programming and I still don't know how to debug and do the C stuff, I came from a Java background.

Edit 1: The user does not write the program to the virtual computer, the programs are already written and the user just redirects with a STDIN  via a command in VIM like this     `(./computer < prog1)` or     `(./computer < prog2)`. The program should compile successfully, and then when the computer figures out what kind of a program it is , it will prompt the user for input depending on it's task. So it could ask the user to input values , then it would calculate their average if that was the program that was redirected to it.

Comment: This question is almost identical to the one you asked an hour ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871531/

Comment: Yes sorry , I was just trying to write it in a more specific and easier to solve form, as people miss understood what's going on

Comment: You can edit your old answer instead of posting several identical ones.

Comment: And you can delete this duplicate question, to save us the trouble of closing it as a dupe.

Comment: It's no trouble at all, closed. @MohammedAl-Huneidi Whenever you need to clarify a question or add additional info, always edit the original question.